# Can viruses survive super-saturated salt solution?

Tags: virology, salt

There is little evidence of biological activity in the *Dead Sea* (a salt-water lake). In addition, human blood cells do not survive in too much salt water as they shrink and die.

So I wondered whether viruses survive in super-saturated salt water. If they survive what allows them to survive and tolerate the high salt concentration? If they do not survive, what is the mechanism of their destruction?

Comment: since viruses may contain no water and are not undergoing metabolic process why do you think salt would affect them?

Answer (score 9):

This issue was studied in [Virus inactivation by salt (NaCl) and phosphate supplemented salt in a 3D collagen matrix model for natural sausage casings](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21632134) *International Journal of Food Microbiology* Volume 148, Pages 128–134.

Saturated NaCl was tested on 4 types of virus, foot-and-mouth-disease virus (FMDV), classical swine fever virus (CSFV), swine vesicular disease virus (SVDV) and African swine fever virus (ASFV) at four different temperatures:4, 12, 20 and 25 °C for a period of 30 days.

For ASFV, but not the other 3 viruses, saturated NaCl had a significant effect of inactivating the virus, on a days timescale.